# How to Bypass Wifi Restriction At School?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, internet

I've asked a question like this on a different thread but got put on hold cause I didn't give enough details. Now I understand what's going on and thought I should re-word the question and ask again.

There's an open WiFi network in my department where students are allowed to connect to, but this network will only allow access to my school's official site only and its sub-domains. Every other website will never load in my browser. I've tried going through a VPN, changing my PC's DNS settings, typing a website's IP address and so on, all to no avail. I then noticed something recently, I tried to access a direct server URL of one of the websites I manage, with a port number in it, it looks like this:

server1.myservername.com:2083

I was able to login to the server (cpanel), download and upload files to the server and do everything on this site in my browser with that unique port number in the URL. That I can access a URL apart from school's is a sign of hope I guess. I also tried an `nslookup` in the `nslookup` app on my PC and found out every website was resolving as a subdomain under my school's site URL.

How can I bypass this restriction? I won't be using this nifty hack for anything illegal, I just need to know how to do this for educational purposes. I'm a computer science student in my first year.

Comment: what happens if you don't include the port number when trying to access your server?

Comment: The browser doesn't load or download any data, it stays on the "connecting" status for about 30s, till I get the error "webpage is not available".

Comment: I would test to see if they have closed off specific ports; however another solution entirely would be to set-up your server to act as a relay; do you know if tor can be run through it?

Comment: Thanks Woody. 1) How do I test for closed ports on the network?  .  2) How Do I setup my own server to act as a relay?  I'm yet to try Tor browser, but I will now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the fence about suggesting this but for educational purposes - why not? ;)

That server of yours that you can get to - by chance is it a windows box? If you werent against it you could set up RDP and see about hitting it on port 3389 from the outside. If it's a linux box you could read up on how to tunnel http traffic through ssh which may be more ideal.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking to do would probably get you into serious trouble with your school.  It would be relatively trivial for them to find you out and what you are doing through various means.  You should talk to the department and network administration, or your student union, about your requirements before trying to hack their system which has been **specifically setup to not allow general internet traffic**.

That said, you have found a hole in their setup.  You could simply setup a remote squid proxy (if you can install software on your server if it is something like a VPS) to tunnel through that hole.

Answer (score 1):

[This can help you with the port scanning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089509/how-to-check-for-opened-ports-on-a-wifi-router) 
As for using your server to connect to the internet, that is quite a bit more difficult, if you can, I'd recommend using Tor if you can, just because of the ease of set-up, but if that's blocked, most likely you will have to setup your server to forward your requests to the proper place (something I don't know how to do yet) sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

if it is lightspeed there is no way to bypass it. It is the most secure wifi blocker. I'v looked into it. I have looked through articles, there website ,and every where else you can think of. The system is put into the hardware of the server router. You would have to change the server router's hardware **and** software.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this solved at the end of the day, I should have gotten a prompt to login to my school's proxy server with a username and password on attempting to launch any foreign sites in my browser.

I found out my internet settings weren't configured to automatically detect proxy servers which was the reason I wasn't getting any dialogue boxes and prompt so I changed Chrome's proxy settings, got the login details from a friend and was able to go online, except that I don't know how to configure all the apps on my pc to connect to this proxy server as only my browser is online.